# jQuery Tic Tac Toe program chooses both combinations when it should only choose one

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tic-tac-toe

I built a little tic-tac-toe program with jQuery. The purpose of the game is to give CPU the first go, and to make it impossible to win. It works to an extent, but there may be bugs I don't know about.

The main problem is that, when the CPU can choose a winning combo, it chooses two instead of only one. An obvious solution feels like it would be to include a `break` statement in the `completeAttempt` loop, but this does not have the desired effect.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var circleIcon = '<i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-2x"></i>';
var crossIcon = '<i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i>';

var userIcon = circleIcon;
var cpuIcon = crossIcon;

var cornersMiddleIds = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
var winningCombos = [[1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]];
var availableNums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

var userIndex = [];
var cpuIndex = [];

var cpuWins = 0;
var draws = 0;

var wonState = false;

Array.prototype.del = function(val){
    if(availableNums.contains(val)){
        availableNums.splice(availableNums.indexOf(val), 1);
    }
}

Array.prototype.contains = function(val){
    return this.indexOf(val) !== -1;
}

cpuInit();

function cpuInit(){
    var cornersOrMiddle = cornersMiddleIds[Math.floor(Math.random() * cornersMiddleIds.length)];
    switch (cornersOrMiddle){
        case 1: $('#one').html(cpuIcon);    cpuIndex.push(1);  availableNums.del(1); break;
        case 3: $('#three').html(cpuIcon);  cpuIndex.push(3);  availableNums.del(3); break;
        case 5: $('#five').html(cpuIcon);   cpuIndex.push(5);  availableNums.del(5); break;
        case 7: $('#seven').html(cpuIcon);  cpuIndex.push(7);  availableNums.del(7); break;
        case 9: $('#nine').html(cpuIcon);   cpuIndex.push(9);  availableNums.del(9); break;
        default:    console.log('error');   break;
    }
}

var counter = 0;

$('#one').click(function(){
    userChooses(1);
    $(this).html(userIcon);
});

$('#two').click(function(){
    userChooses(2);
    $(this).html(userIcon);
});

$('#three').click(function(){
    userChooses(3);
    $(this).html(userIcon);
});

$('#four').click(function(){
    userChooses(4);
    $(this).html(userIcon);
});

$('#five').click(function(){
    userChooses(5);
    $(this).html(userIcon);
});

$('#six').click(function(){
    userChooses(6);
    $(this).html(userIcon);
});

$('#seven').click(function(){
    userChooses(7);
    $(this).html(userIcon);
});

$('#eight').click(function(){
    userChooses(8);
    $(this).html(userIcon);
});

$('#nine').click(function(){
    userChooses(9);
    $(this).html(userIcon);
});

function userChooses(val){
    if(!userIndex.contains(val) && !cpuIndex.contains(val)) {
        userIndex.push(val);
        availableNums.del(val);
        cpuChoosesBasedOnUserChoiceOf(val);
        checkIfWon();
    }
}

function cpuSelects(num){
    if(cpuIndex.indexOf(num) === -1 && userIndex.indexOf(num) === -1){
        switch (num) {
            case 1:
                $('#one').html(cpuIcon);
                cpuIndex.push(1);
                availableNums.del(1);
                break;
            case 2:
                $('#two').html(cpuIcon);
                cpuIndex.push(2);
                availableNums.del(2);
                break;
            case 3:
                $('#three').html(cpuIcon);
                cpuIndex.push(3);
                availableNums.del(3);
                break;
            case 4:
                $('#four').html(cpuIcon);
                cpuIndex.push(4);
                availableNums.del(4);
                break;
            case 5:
                $('#five').html(cpuIcon);
                cpuIndex.push(5);
                availableNums.del(5);
                break;
            case 6:
                $('#six').html(cpuIcon);
                cpuIndex.push(6);
                availableNums.del(6);
                break;
            case 7:
                $('#seven').html(cpuIcon);
                cpuIndex.push(7);
                availableNums.del(7);
                break;
            case 8:
                $('#eight').html(cpuIcon);
                cpuIndex.push(8);
                availableNums.del(8);
                break;
            case 9:
                $('#nine').html(cpuIcon);
                cpuIndex.push(9);
                availableNums.del(9);
                break;
        }
    }
}

var completeAttempt = function(arr){
    for(var i = 0; i < winningCombos.length; i++){
        if(arr.contains(winningCombos[i][0]) && arr.contains(winningCombos[i][1])){
            cpuSelects(winningCombos[i][2]);

        } else if(arr.contains(winningCombos[i][1]) && arr.contains(winningCombos[i][2])){
            cpuSelects(winningCombos[i][0]);

        } else if(arr.contains(winningCombos[i][0]) && arr.contains(winningCombos[i][2])){
            cpuSelects(winningCombos[i][1]);
        }
    }
};

var blockAttempt = function(arr){
    for(var i = 0; i < winningCombos.length; i++){
        if(arr.contains(winningCombos[i][0]) && arr.contains(winningCombos[i][1])){
                cpuSelects(winningCombos[i][2]);


        } else if(arr.contains(winningCombos[i][1]) && arr.contains(winningCombos[i][2])){
                cpuSelects(winningCombos[i][0]);


        } else if(arr.contains(winningCombos[i][0]) && arr.contains(winningCombos[i][2])){
                cpuSelects(winningCombos[i][1]);
        }
    }
};

function winBlockRand(){
    var len = availableNums.length;
    completeAttempt(cpuIndex);
    if(len === availableNums.length){
        console.log('cpu tried to win and now will block user');
        blockAttempt(userIndex);
        if(len === availableNums.length){
            console.log('cpu could not block user, so is choosing itself');
            cpuSelects(availableNums[Math.floor(Math.random() * availableNums.length)]);
        }
    }
    counter++;
}

function cpuChoosesBasedOnUserChoiceOf(userVal){
    console.log(counter);

    if(counter === 4){
        winBlockRand();
    }

    if(counter === 3){
        winBlockRand();
    }

    if(counter === 2){
        winBlockRand();
    }

    if(counter === 1){
        winBlockRand();
    }

    if(counter === 0) {
        // ROUND 1: Cpu chose the middle
        if (cpuIndex.contains(5)) {
            console.log('cpuIndex contains 5');
            switch (userVal) {
                case 1:
                    cpuSelects(9);
                    counter++;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cpuSelects(7);
                    counter++;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    cpuSelects(3);
                    counter++;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    cpuSelects(1);
                    counter++;
                    break;
                default:
                    cpuSelects(9);
                    counter++;
                    break;
            }
        } else if(userVal === 5){
        // ROUND 1: Cpu chose a corner and I just chose middle
            if(cpuIndex.contains(1)){
                cpuSelects(9);
            } else if(cpuIndex.contains(3)){
                cpuSelects(7);
            } else if(cpuIndex.contains(7)){
                cpuSelects(3);
            } else if(cpuIndex.contains(9)){
                cpuSelects(1);
            }
        // I mistakenly did not choose middle
        } else {
            cpuSelects(5);
        }
        counter++;
    }
}

function resetBoard(){
    cpuIndex = [];
    $('td').html('');
    availableNums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    counter = 0;
    userIndex = [];
    wonState = false;
    cpuInit();
}

function isInUserArray(element){
    return userIndex.indexOf(element) !== -1;
}

function isInCpuArray(element){
    return cpuIndex.indexOf(element) !== -1;
}

function checkIfWon(){
    console.log('available nums: ' + availableNums);
    console.log('user has: ' + userIndex);
    console.log('cpu has: ' + cpuIndex);
    for(var i = 0; i < winningCombos.length; i++){
        if(winningCombos[i].every(isInCpuArray)){
            custom_alert('CPU wins!');
            wonState = true;
            cpuWins++;
            $('#cpuWins').html(cpuWins.toString());
            break;
        }
    }
    if(availableNums.length === 0 && !wonState){
        custom_alert('Game drawn!');
        draws++;
        $('#draws').html(draws.toString());
    }
}

function custom_alert(output_msg) {

    $("<div></div>").html(output_msg).dialog({
        height: 150,
        width: 200,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        position: { my: "top", at: "top", of: window },
        buttons: [
            {
                text: "Ok",
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    resetBoard();
                }
            }
        ]
    });
}
```

});

[github version here.](http://alanbuchanan.github.io/tictactoe/)

Other issues:
- The jQueryUI alert does not appear as it should in Codepen, which leads to the entire thing acting buggy. [codepen version here.](http://codepen.io/alanbuchanan/pen/BoLWvK?editors=001)

Comment: Add comments to your code so we can follow your logic and see what you are trying to do with the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can `return` a winning choice. [codepen](http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/LpRLeL?editors=001)

```
var completeAttempt = function (arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < winningCombos.length; i++) {
    if (arr.contains(winningCombos[i][0]) && arr.contains(winningCombos[i][1])){
      return cpuSelects(winningCombos[i][2])
    } else if (arr.contains(winningCombos[i][1]) && arr.contains(winningCombos[i][2])) {
      return cpuSelects(winningCombos[i][0])
    } else if (arr.contains(winningCombos[i][0]) && arr.contains(winningCombos[i][2])) {
      return cpuSelects(winningCombos[i][1])
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work as expected; if CPU can win, it opts not to. [Screenshot of what I mean](http://i.imgur.com/k1rukFd.png)

Comment: @alanbuchanan Oh I see, you're calling `completeAttempt` earlier than I would have expected. Maybe split that function into `noWinningChoiceYet` and `winningChoiceAvailable` for when there's only one more move left to win.

Answer (score -1):

I think there are few issues with your code(will update my answer, later) but a reason for your dialogs not working is that you have a bad path in your config

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js
```

Should be

```
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js
```

This will get the dialogs to work.

Also looking at your css you also have path issues there as well.

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css
//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

should be

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css
http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Edit, i have looked through the code and added comments and simplified it. Take a look below. I did not go through all the code but it gives you an idea on how to go about making other changes.

What i have suggested above did not work my Chrome 45, until i have changed the location, not sure if it was based on my security settings but it did work in FF and IE without any changes (odd behaviour).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http:////maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://alanbuchanan.github.io/tictactoe/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<style>
table {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}

td {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.left-col {
    border-right: 8px solid black;
}

.middle-col {
    border-right: 8px solid black;
}

.top-row, .middle-row {
    border-bottom: 8px solid black;
}

h3 {
    text-align: right;
}

.ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    visibility: hidden;
}

</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Define the player icons
    var userIcon = '<i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-2x"></i>';
    var cpuIcon = '<i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i>';

    // Define board positions
  var cornersMiddleIds = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
  var winningCombos = [
    [1, 5, 9],
    [3, 5, 7],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [3, 6, 9]
  ];
  var availableNums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

  // Define the play positions
  var userIndex = [];
  var cpuIndex = [];

  // Define the win counts
  var cpuWins = 0;
  var draws = 0;

  // Define if the game is won
  var wonState = false;

  // Initalize move counter
  var counter = 0;

  // Define array delete prototype
  Array.prototype.del = function(val) {
    if (availableNums.contains(val)) {
      availableNums.splice(availableNums.indexOf(val), 1);
    }
  };

  // Define array contains prototype
  Array.prototype.contains = function(val) {
    return this.indexOf(val) !== -1;
  };

  // Start the game by asking the cpu to play
  cpuInit();

  // Function that calls the cpu player to peform a move first
  function cpuInit() {
    // Chose a random location on the board
    var cornersOrMiddle = cornersMiddleIds[Math.floor(Math.random() * cornersMiddleIds.length)];

    // Based on the choice perform the move
    // Only choose a move that is a corner or middle
    // other choices will make the player go first
    switch (cornersOrMiddle) {
      case 1:
      case 3:
      case 5:
      case 7:
      case 9:
        cpuPlay(cornersOrMiddle);
        break;
      default:
        console.log('error');
        break;
    }
  }

  // Perform a cpu move
  function cpuPlay(move){
     // Check if this move is valid
    if (availableNums.contains(move)) {
         // Mark the location
         $('[data-location="' + move + '"]').html(cpuIcon);

        // Add the cpu play into array
        cpuIndex.push(move);

        // Delete the location out of avaliable locations
        availableNums.del(move);
        }
  }

  // Handle user choosing a move
  $('[data-location]').click(function(event){
        // Button that triggered the modal
        var eventTarget = $(event.currentTarget);

        // Extract info from data-* attributes
        var location = eventTarget.data('location');

      // Call the human play
      humanPlay(this, location);
  });

  // Pefrom human move and check if the move is valid
  function humanPlay(htmlReference, location){
      // Check if this move is valid
    if (availableNums.contains(location)) {

      // Mark the location as human
      $(htmlReference).html(userIcon);

      // Add the move to the huma location
      userIndex.push(location);

      // Remove the move from the avaliable locations
      availableNums.del(location);

      // Call the cpu to make am move
      cpuChoosesBasedOnUserChoiceOf(location);

      // Check if the game is finished
      checkIfWon();
    }
  }

  // Reset all the game variables
  function resetBoard() {
     // Set avaliable locations 
     availableNums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

      // Reset the cpu moves
    cpuIndex = [];

    // Reset the user moves
    userIndex = [];

    // Reset the board moves
    $('td').html('');

    // Set game counter to 0
    counter = 0;

    // Set finish state as false
    wonState = false;

    // Call the cpu to make a move
    cpuInit();
  }

  // Check if the location is in the user array
  function isInUserArray(element) {
    return userIndex.indexOf(element) !== -1;
  }

  // Check if the location is in the cpu array
  function isInCpuArray(element) {
    return cpuIndex.indexOf(element) !== -1;
  }

  // Play a specific winning attempt
  function completeAttempt(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < winningCombos.length; i++) {
      if (arr.contains(winningCombos[i][0]) && arr.contains(winningCombos[i][1])) {
        cpuPlay(winningCombos[i][2]);
      } else if (arr.contains(winningCombos[i][1]) && arr.contains(winningCombos[i][2])) {
        cpuPlay(winningCombos[i][0]);
      } else if (arr.contains(winningCombos[i][0]) && arr.contains(winningCombos[i][2])) {
        cpuPlay(winningCombos[i][1]);
      }
    }
  }

  // Play a specific blocking attempt
  function blockAttempt(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < winningCombos.length; i++) {
      if (arr.contains(winningCombos[i][0]) && arr.contains(winningCombos[i][1])) {
        cpuPlay(winningCombos[i][2]);

      } else if (arr.contains(winningCombos[i][1]) && arr.contains(winningCombos[i][2])) {
        cpuPlay(winningCombos[i][0]);

      } else if (arr.contains(winningCombos[i][0]) && arr.contains(winningCombos[i][2])) {
        cpuPlay(winningCombos[i][1]);
      }
    }
  }

  // Try to block random location
  function winBlockRand() {
    var len = availableNums.length;
    completeAttempt(cpuIndex);
    if (len === availableNums.length) {
      console.log('cpu tried to win and now will block user');
      blockAttempt(userIndex);
      if (len === availableNums.length) {
        console.log('cpu could not block user, so is choosing itself');
        cpuPlay(availableNums[Math.floor(Math.random() * availableNums.length)]);
      }
    }
    counter++;
  }

  // Chose the cpu move based on the last user move
  function cpuChoosesBasedOnUserChoiceOf(userVal) {
    console.log(counter);

    if (counter === 4) {
      winBlockRand();
    }

    if (counter === 3) {
      winBlockRand();
    }

    if (counter === 2) {
      winBlockRand();
    }

    if (counter === 1) {
      winBlockRand();
    }

    if (counter === 0) {
      // ROUND 1: Cpu chose the middle
      if (cpuIndex.contains(5)) {
        console.log('cpuIndex contains 5');
        switch (userVal) {
          case 1:
            cpuPlay(9);
            counter++;
            break;
          case 3:
            cpuPlay(7);
            counter++;
            break;
          case 7:
            cpuPlay(3);
            counter++;
            break;
          case 9:
            cpuPlay(1);
            counter++;
            break;
          default:
            cpuPlay(9);
            counter++;
            break;
        }
      } else if (userVal === 5) {
        // ROUND 1: Cpu chose a corner and I just chose middle
        if (cpuIndex.contains(1)) {
          cpuPlay(9);
        } else if (cpuIndex.contains(3)) {
          cpuPlay(7);
        } else if (cpuIndex.contains(7)) {
          cpuPlay(3);
        } else if (cpuIndex.contains(9)) {
          cpuPlay(1);
        }
        // I mistakenly did not choose middle
      } else {
        cpuPlay(5);
      }
      counter++;
    }
  }

  // Check if the game has been won
  function checkIfWon() {
    console.log('available nums: ' + availableNums);
    console.log('user has: ' + userIndex);
    console.log('cpu has: ' + cpuIndex);
    for (var i = 0; i < winningCombos.length; i++) {
      if (winningCombos[i].every(isInCpuArray)) {
        custom_alert('CPU wins!');
        wonState = true;
        cpuWins++;
        $('#cpuWins').html(cpuWins.toString());
        break;
      }
    }
    if (availableNums.length === 0 && !wonState) {
      custom_alert('Game drawn!');
      draws++;
      $('#draws').html(draws.toString());
    }
  }

  // Show an alern if the game is over
  function custom_alert(output_msg) {

    $("<div></div>").html(output_msg).dialog({
      height: 170,
      width: 220,
      dialogClass: 'custom-ui-widget-header-warning',
      modal: true,
      position: {
        my: "top",
        at: "top",
        of: window
      },
      buttons: [{
        text: "Ok",
        click: function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
          resetBoard();
        }
      }]
    });
  }
});
</script>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>noughts and crosses</h1>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td id="one" data-location="1" class="left-col top-row"></td>
                    <td id="two" data-location="2" class="middle-col top-row"></td>
                    <td id="three" data-location="3" class="right-col top-row"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="four" data-location="4" class="left-col middle-row"></td>
                    <td id="five" data-location="5" class="middle-col middle-row"></td>
                    <td id="six" data-location="6" class="right-col middle-row"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="seven" data-location="7" class="left-col bottom-row"></td>
                    <td id="eight" data-location="8" class="middle-col bottom-row"></td>
                    <td id="nine" data-location="9" class="right-col bottom-row"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <h3>
            Draws <span id="draws">0</span> - <span id="cpuWins">0</span> CPU
        </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: They are 'protocol relative' links and work fine. http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/